# how to import data from sql-server2008 to excel with visual studio express 2013

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, visual-studio-2012

i have a little problem with my code..

i want to open an excel file and import the data from sql server 2008 to excel field..

can you help me with the code?? im using visual studio express 2013 for windows desktop and sql server 2008 as the database..

this is my code..

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class F_Tunggal

Private Sub cmdproses_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdproses.Click

        Dim xlApp As excel.Application
        Dim i, j As Integer
        Dim xlWorkBook As excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As excel.Worksheet
        Dim xlRange As excel.Range
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        Dim sql As String
        con = New SqlConnection(connection) 'con, cmd, connection, i already public declare at 1 module..'
        cmd = New SqlCommand()
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        xlApp = New excel.Application
        xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsx")
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks(1)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(1)
        sql = "select [Data] from [Statistik].[dbo].[T_DataTunggal] Where [Kode_Project]= '" + kodeproject + "'"
        Dim dscmd As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        dscmd.Fill(ds)

        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(j)
            Next
        Next
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\test.xlsx")
        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()

        releaseobject(xlApp)
        releaseobject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseobject(xlWorkSheet)

        con.Close()
        MsgBox("you can find the file C:\test.xlsx")
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

from the code above.. i got an error at : xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\test.xlsx")

when i go to drive C:\ to find the saved file, i don't found it..

please help me
sorry if my english so bad..
thx..

Comment: what does the error message say? do you have permissions to create a file on C:\?

Comment: this is the error i got..

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Statistik.exe

Additional information: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\7AFE7900'. There are several possible reasons:



• The file name or path does not exist.

• The file is being used by another program.

• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook. @PrfctByDsgn

Comment: how to know that i have the permission to create new file on c:\ ?? i'm using windows 8.1

Comment: you could just try to create a text file there using windows explorer

Comment: yeah.. i cant create txt.. an error message pop up.. error 0x80070522 : a required privilege is not held by the client..

how i fix this?? thx @PrfctByDsgn

Comment: just write your file to a folder where you have write access ... like your documents folder ("C:\users\<username>\documents")

Comment: thx a lot @PrfctByDsgn.. my problem solved now.. i write the file to D:\ instead of C:\
and now i have no problem with this anymore..

Answer (score 0):

Usually on client system we don't have privilege to create file in C:. It's admin right to install or uninstall any software so admin have this privilege not the associate using system. If possible try changing your drive or try to save information on your dekstop (like C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop where XXXX will be your user id.) or documents folder becuase they are defined for the users to use.